# How to get HTTP context from ApplicationDbContext.OnConfiguring?

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, httpcontext

I'm authenticating HTTP requests in middleware by querying data in the database, and to do so I need to configure the ApplicationDbContext with the data in HTTP request. How can I reach HTTP request from ApplicationDbContext.OnConfiguring ? (ASP .NET core / Entity framework core)

**Middleware**

```
public class TeamAuthentication
{
    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context, ApplicationDbContext db)
    {
        My.CheckToken(db);
        // ...
```

**DbContext**

```
public class ApplicationDbContext :  IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    private ILoggerFactory loggerFactory;

    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options, ILoggerFactory _loggerFactory)
        : base(options)
    {
        loggerFactory = _loggerFactory;
    }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        // how to reach HttpContext here ?
        // ...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have already found, EF supports using DbContext with a dependency injection container. Inject `IHttpContextAccessor` in your dependencies and use it to obtain the current HttpContext:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext :  IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
   private readonly ILoggerFactory _loggerFactory;
   private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _contextAccessor;

   public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory, IHttpContextAccessor contextAccessor)
    : base(options)
   {
       _loggerFactory = loggerFactory;
       _contextAccessor = contextAccessor;
   }

   protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
   {
       // use _contextAccessor.HttpContext here
       ...
   }
```

And do not forget to register `IHttpContextAccessor` to DI in ConfigureServices as "[The IHttpContextAccessor service is not registered by default](https://github.com/aspnet/Hosting/issues/793)"

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddSingleton<Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.IHttpContextAccessor, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HttpContextAccessor>();
    ...
}
```